# Animate css creates an transparent field over divs

Tags: animation, meteor, animate.css

I'm using animate.css to add some transistions to my meteor app. However, there is this problem that animate.css creates an almost transparant overlay over my buttons/images etc.

I have a main div where the animate.css class is added depending on changing page views etc. Very simplified this is my HTML.

```
<body>
  <header class="header></header>
  <div class="animate-holder {{animated class}}>
     <div class="class1></div>
     <div class="class2></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

From what I've tested this will happen all the time and it doesn't matter how I use transistions. Is there a simple way to NOT have this overlay?

EDIT:

I can hack it like this, but this is very very ugly. But maybe it creates more insight into the problem:

```
Template.DetailsSubmit.rendered = function() {
  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    var classes = $('div.animated').attr('class');
    $('div.animated').removeClass(classes);
  }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this specific div clickable through using the very useful (and not famous enough) `pointer-events` css property:

```
div.animated {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```